# Keycloak fails to authorize client from local php server, but return ok when using postman

Tags: php, curl, keycloak

I've setup local php server and wanted to get authorization token from keycloak.

I've send request like this:

```
$url = "http://docker:10040/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
$data = "client_id=postman&username=admin&password=12345&grant_type=password"
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

if ($data)
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

but this returns to me:

```
{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client secret not provided in request"}
```

Now, this would obviously be the case of "you don't have such client", right? Except when I do send "basically" the same request using postman:

```
POST /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token? HTTP/1.1
Host: docker:10040
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c08c2144-4ea0-45ad-ab16-150db7768825
```

last line is body, but it's not readable so let's rephrase it:

```
grant_type:password
username:admin
password:12345
client_id:postman
```

So as you see, basically same. Except maybe postman token.

Result of postman is correct answer that does include access_token:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxWjZ0SXNXa2JLSUNkSG96eWJHT1QybU90S1p1T3RiMU9lNWVRTlZzLW5ZIn0.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.Ojw34yZkNmeTBvD7M1OTLv5PRnPcNO7nxf5d_w8yh_zuGTXCwPEyKm1blfpBDYkrKtjbwnamwWWZeBKYzLCUwebnE5rrEDG13fKC3iTdqkh5tEYMRhn8C8LAGBPy6uVhWJyL2X9CCbNQNNTiBUD3Ida6EK1K0rreoSpWInHgEktBumpleFdznCUHoZe6-xina5S4yC1TtZOWtSl4nrBgrn720uqmg-lN6_HacV6YnldYmtJWr_ay7EvmTAc4KLh5XU6YyulcXrq7Z921Zqupe3VJRhhFNssWYqT7c_bIGao5HYTgcmOnRsp_iGuT_6ku2LFEKXrLxmVJDaM9ok_3lA",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxWjZ0SXNXa2JLSUNkSG96eWJHT1QybU90S1p1T3RiMU9lNWVRTlZzLW5ZIn0.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.UTqGzJEnwzjsYnAIGvFafyJCWpmjVMjttvByX7r-KGtgmiqeKvVFSnisAIic8S8n6lHvAtW_K3s35CWovofHJqia9kEk2eyNZIZQGDM8LCum2KgKBOv4Jqg8H3F54gQzr4Pd17SbavpU38--FqDOHMX8a6L6GLs7yUy7PZ86MTm-B4V49ckleCGt0qMtzXMn8GmA1PnjCk5VpB_XR2FSEzuGfFwiXtq3HmWEGL-EybGRj-1GVNi568N2O1tKrHu8SeM-cg8KHEs5oa_C_lpCTii0OqVx7-NInaPpabua1QjrVtPtqS2f1dXuSMmVNwFRPw8ANHxmK4U9zFLgkBloxg",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxWjZ0SXNXa2JLSUNkSG96eWJHT1QybU90S1p1T3RiMU9lNWVRTlZzLW5ZIn0.eyJqdGkiOiIyMGY1OTgzMC05MTFiLTQwNTctYWFiMi05N2NiZGJhNDEwNDMiLCJleHAiOjE1NTI0MDE1NjMsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTUyNDAxMjYzLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vZG9ja2VyOjEwMDQwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zLzFzcGlubWlsbGlvbmFpcmUiLCJhdWQiOiJwb3N0bWFuIiwic3ViIjoiMjFlMjc5MmEtNGQ1NS00YTVjLTlmNDctNDcxMDA5ZTEzNmFiIiwidHlwIjoiSUQiLCJhenAiOiJwb3N0bWFuIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjowLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiZTQyNjhiNDctZDNmNy00NDExLWJiZjctYzgzMTk5NTBlYTY5IiwiYWNyIjoiMSIsIm5hbWUiOiIiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.tf1erOZwlXfIklEfx-RtHQvFA4ioMrgZUQYup1sPDQvrZIJJlUf_S6TtJXb226xLWHpyrBKiX6BHJmq6wKCNdOHwP1Rzr7toA7AdfqtRUtTpvW5ZyfzJod4u3wd55u6W5GFCfHPnaOrNEVexKT8HIEty35l110iX2eOAzVB9JBJ5OsJl9PkJzrAct3DhIchaqwWKPrVD2kebyRVNk4RlNJmRzDsH1br4Wv2F9Tjny5ShffzBbCn47LZDQBOO4VbcGgmzyrpYJ70l1DSChdL3chVihwPttA6kiQUYCux1wQd5MSue8Yu7u-YZbXXswOy9ZXU3mfWDdN2I1u4wX3T7UA",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "e4268b47-d3f7-4411-bbf7-c8319950ea69"
}
```

What am I missing? To me they look the same. The main difference is obviously that one is send through postman/client, while the other is send via server-based php script. I don't see there posibility for problem. Am I wrong?

How can I send curl via php to keycloak so that it returns to me access token?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you:

1. Change client setting as public instead of "confidential" in Access Type combobox (in Client setting)
2. Add the parameter in request like:

   `&grant_type=password&client_secret=your_secret_client_value`

   Refer to http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Client-secret-not-provided-in-request-td1936.html